# What is the most straightforward way to visualize color-coded clusters along with the cluster centers?

Tags: clustering, visualization, k-means, matplotlib, seaborn

I have applied the kMeans Clustering algorithm to a dataframe and have gained cluster labels for each row. I had selected only two features.
There are 4 clusters.
I want to visualize the datapoints in 2D plane with color-coded clusters which I want to look like this-

[image: 1]

Ignore the labels. I would like to plot cluster centers instead.
I have looked in many blog posts, articles etc. None was helpful.
What is the most straightforward to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There can be multiple ways, one can be* -

- Plot the points with *hue=cluster_number*

- Plot the Centroid with a different markers

**Code** *for 3 Clusters on 2 Iris Features* -

```py
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data  
y = iris.target
X=X[:,:-2]
X = (X - X.mean())/X.std()

def create_cluster(k=3):
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)

    kmeans.fit(X)
    return kmeans

kmeans = create_cluster()
y_pred = kmeans.predict(X)
centroid = kmeans.cluster_centers_

_, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,6))
color = ["#e74c3c", "#34495e", "#2ecc71"]
sns.scatterplot(X[:,0],X[:,1], hue=y_pred, palette=sns.color_palette(color),ax=ax)
sns.pointplot(centroid[:,0], centroid[:,1],markers='^',join=False,ax=ax)
```

$\hspace{2cm}$**Output** - *Ignore the convergence quality*

$\hspace{2cm}$
[image]